# Trace plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

```
using Gadfly;
bb=randn(20,2)
plot(x=bb[:,1],y=bb[:,2],Geom.line)
```

[image]

but I want plot the trace of all the point, so that I can get a plot like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to draw a path' curve with x and y values

`plot(Geom.line(preserve_order=true), Geom.point, x=bb[:,1], y=bb[:,2])`

or

`plot(Geom.path, x=bb[:,1], y=bb[:,2])`

i get this
[image]

Comment: Ok，it's the answer I want .

Comment: Or [`Geom.path`](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/geoms/geom_path.html#Geom.path-1), which is an alias for `Geom.line(preserve_order=true)`.